# Autoconnect to UltraVNC machine using password in a script, but the hostname (VNC Server) is always empty

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, script, vnc, gui

[VNC Server Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqER0.png)
I'm making an GUI using PowerShell with a listbox and in that listbox there are hostnames. When I select it and hit connect, it should connect to that machine without entering a password. UltraVNC does start and tries to connect, but the VNC Server field is always empty while, usually it always shows the hostname of the machine you're connecting to. I'm pulling the hostname from the listbox.SelectedItem function. I made a test label to see if the variable holds the right value and it does.

When I remove that variable and use an actual hostname, it also doesn't work. It's still empty. Here's the code that is supposed to handle that:

```
$vncForm_Load= {
    cd "C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC"
    $PW = "password"
    ForEach ($VNCHost In Get-Content "A:\VNC Hosts.txt")
        {
            $hostsListbox.Items.Add($VNCHost)
        }
}

$connectButton_Click={
    #$testLabel.Text = $hostsListbox.SelectedItem
    $conHost = $hostsListbox.SelectedItem
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe" -ArgumentList "-autoreconnect 30, -connect $conHost, -password $PW"
```

When I use the following command in CMD, it works perfectly (I know it's not safe to pass passwords in variables or plain text, but this is only locally):

```
vncviewer.exe -autoreconnect 30 -connect HOSTNAME::PORT -password password
```

I figured I just tweaked it a bit to make is usable for PowerShell, but that doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong... (I've attached a picture of what the VNC Server field says when I use it in the script)

Comment: Remove the commas between the arguments in the `-ArgumentList` items. If cmd does not need commas, then neither should the values in the  `-ArgumentList` parameter of the `Start-Process` cmdlet. I believe that's all you need to do, then should be good-to-go (i.e. `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe" -ArgumentList "-autoreconnect 30 -connect $conHost -password $PW"`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I tried that and unfortunately it didn't work. I got the same result.

Comment: What error message are you getting exactly? Also, please show the content or a sample of what is in `A:\VNC Hosts.txt`. Both those thing may be useful in providing further troubleshooting detail. Show a before what's in the file and show an after what is in that file since you are adding to it. I'd like to see both.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. I made a button to edit A:\VNC Hosts.txt and after that, the newly added host is being showed in the listbox. I would've made a separate button for that, but I have a limitation of 5 controls....

The content of A:\VNC Hosts.txt is:
PC1
PC2
PC3

Comment: Would you mind to start just using that logic I provided in my first comment, but please run it manually plugging in the expected and desired values rather than using variable to confirm that that work. If that does not work, then it work different that I expected but if that does work, then it may imply that the variable values are not what is expected and desired when you run those. Everything makes sense including the listbox. I actually switched to WPF dropdown box rather than using the forms in PowerShell scripts myself. Let me know how that goes though please.

Comment: I'll do that soon, within 2 days. You wil hear from me.